# Cleaning weather data and calculate mean

Tags: r

I have a daily minimum temperature, maximum temperature, minimum dew point and maximum dew point.This data contains NaN, so i want to do various operations;

1. calculate the percent of NaN in the column by year along with total percent throughout the period( 1948-2018)
2. If the percentage NaN of the year exceeds more than 10% then exclude all the data of that particular year if less than include for calculation.
3. Calculate the yearly mean temperature taking maximum and minimum temperature if it follows rule 2.
   4.Calculate the yearly mean dew point taking maximum and minimum dew point temperature
4. calculate yearly minimum temperature, maximum temperature, minimum dew point, and maximum dew point of if it follows rule 2
5. from the result of 3, 4, and 5. I want to make a trend graphs year Vs Variable.
6. I want to run t tests on each variable as well.

My data looks like

```
 Station Date    Month  Day Year    MaxTemp MinTemp MaxDewPoint MinDewPoint
    ORD 1/1/1948    1   1   1948    35.6    26.6    34.16         -27.4
    ORD 1/2/1948    1   2   1948    -2      -16     -16.96       -27.04
    ORD 1/3/1948    1   3   1948    -4      -26     -12            -26
    ORD 1/4/1948    1   4   1948    -5      -26     -15             -26
    ORD 1/5/1948    1   5   1948    8       -25     3               NaN
    ORD 1/6/1948    1   6   1948    -11     -25     -24            -25
    ORD 1/7/1948    1   7   1948    1       -23     NaN            -23
    ORD 1/8/1948    1   8   1948    1       -22     -9              NaN
    ORD 1/9/1948    1   9   1948    NaN     -22     -5             -22
    ORD 1/10/1948   1   10  1948    10      NaN     -2              -22
    ORD 1/11/1948   1   11  1948    -11     -21    -23              -21
    ORD 1/12/1948   1   12  1948    3       -12     -7.96        -20.92
    ORD 1/13/1948   1   13  1948    6.98    -7.6    -7.6         -20.2
    ORD 1/14/1948   1   14  1948    3.92    -9.4    -11.2        NaN
    ORD 1/15/1948   1   15  1948    6        -7    -5.98         NaN
    ORD 1/16/1948   1   16  1948    3       -11     -7.96       -20.02
```

So far i manage to write few lines of code but i am not sure if it is right code and the most efficient one.

```
install.packages("dplyr")
install.packages("stringr")
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

#setting up workspace in the folder#
setwd("E:/Climate Data Analysis/Asignment 1")
#opening a CSV file in r program#
data<- read.csv("chiacagost.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
#making data frame of the variables#
dframe<- data.frame(data)
# Missing percentage of the data by column
MisMxTMP<-dframe%>%summarise(NAMisMxTMP=sum(is.na(Max.Temp)/length(Max.Temp)))*100
misMnTMP<-dframe%>%summarise(NAmisMnTMPL=sum(is.na(Min.Temp)/length(Min.Temp)))*100
MisMxDTMP<-dframe%>%summarise(NAMisMxDTMP=sum(is.na(Max.Dew.Point)/length(Max.Dew.Point)))*100
MisMnDTMP<-dframe%>%summarise(NAMisMnDTMP=sum(is.na(Min.Dew.Point)/length(Min.Dew.Point)))*100

#Calcualte Mean temperature and dew point

MeanTMP<-dframe%>% mutate(MeanTMP=rowMeans(cbind(dframe$Max.Temp,dframe$Min.Temp),na.rm=TRUE))
#Minimum Dew point had more than 12 percent of missing data but i could not locate which years so the code below doesnot exclude NA
MeanDTMP<-dframe%>% mutate(MeanDTMP=rowMeans(cbind(dframe$Max.Dew.Point,dframe$Min.Dew.Point),na.rm=TRUE))
```

From this results i intend to get yearly trends of all 4 variables individually (theil-sen and OLS, and run t-test. Include all the results in the trend graph.

Comment: Could you also format your data as you've done for the code?

Comment: I would suggest focusing on one question at a time. You can probably make a better example that focuses on strictly that particular problem. You can always ask more questions or search for similar questions.